# writing data into a database using sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am brand new to iphone ,I have created a table in sqlite database and I have a page with some text fields, now how can i insert the data which are taken from text fields into the existing table using sqlite ,can any body give me some example code or tutorial

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use coreData. Good tutorial to start [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started)

And [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)